# Why does this chained conditional operator throw NPE?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, runtime-error, conditional-operator

```
Boolean isTrue = condition1 ? true : (
                                id == null ? null : condition2);
```

When condition1 returns true, the code runs fine(makes sense), but when condition1 is false, the code fails with a null pointer exception.
Try it yourself - https://www.ideone.com/epj9Jd

This is slightly confusing and doesn't make sense. An explanation for this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the actual full code.

Comment: In short because `id == null ? >> null <<`.  Use `false` or `Boolean.FALSE` instead.

Comment: Or, better, a [mcve].

Comment: The code on ideone doesn't throw an exception

Comment: @StephenC why would that cause an NPE? `Boolean` (capital B) can hold `null` just fine.

Comment: Indeed.  But then you unbox it.  And unboxing a `null` throws an NPE.

Comment: The trick to *understanding* this is that the type of a conditional expression is determined by the 2nd operand not the 3rd one.  But the real trick is to avoid using `null` as a `Boolean` ... 'cos it creates problems.

Comment: @StephenC Interesting. I would have expected better type inference here.

Comment: if we compare(using ==) null variables with any value other than null. it throws NPE. The reason is sometimes the operator may try to access the object's member. It is always best approach to not use null variables in complex comparision.

Comment: @sachin that's false. `==` only does reference equality for objects. It never accesses members.

Comment: @sachin - the real explanation is nothing to do with `==`.  See my answer for the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Boolean isTrue = condition1 ? true : (
                            id == null ? null /* <- HERE*/ : condition2);
```

OK, so this is a bit gnarly.  The problem is due to the `null` value introduced at the point labeled `HERE` being unboxed.

Why?

Because the type of `condition1 ? true : ...` is the type of the 2nd operand; i.e. `boolean`.  Therefore the subexpression `id == null ? null : condition2` which is `Boolean` has to be unboxed to a `boolean`.

But unboxing a `null` gives you a NPE.

---

> Interesting. I would have expected better type inference here.

Unfortunately, the rules for typing of conditional expressions involving boxed types were solidified in Java 5 when autoboxing / unboxing were added to the language.  That was 15 (?) years before Java got significant support for type inferencing.

Once the rules were solidified, they couldn't be changed ... without breaking backwards compatibility.

(But actually this is not a type inference problem.  The typing is fine.  The real problem here is that there are two possible semantics for this, one that involves unboxing `null` and the other that doesn't.  The JLS rules for typing conditionals mean that the first one is used in this case.)